# How Do you add/substract from previous row in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

In Mysql

Table

```
Id AA BBB 
A  45 123
B  52 120
C  40 135
```

How would I get

```
B_A  7 
A_C  5
```

First would need to sort by BBB Asc
then minus 52-45. 
B_A concatenate B and A

How Do you add/substract form previous row in SQL?

If I needed to have seperate cols for B then A, How Would I add this.

Comment: Is the Id column always perfectly contiguous (i.e., no gaps from one row to the next)?

Comment: How do you get 5 for the second row in your output?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT concat(t1.id , '_',  t2.id, ' ', t1.aa - t2.aa ) 
FROM   table t1 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT Max(t2.id) prev_id, 
                          t1.id 
                   FROM   table t1 
                          INNER JOIN table t2 
                            ON t1.id > t2.id
                   GROUP BY t1.id) prev 
         ON t1.id = prev.id 
       INNER JOIN table t2 
         ON t2.id = prev.prev_id
```

Comment: there are more than just two rows. Damn, sorry adding to q

Comment: @user428862 I'd forgotten the Group By Clause and I got the Concat to work. See updated answer

Comment: There are more than two rows...75 -80. rows.

Comment: @user428862 the number of rows isn't a problem. Its the the second row in the output that confusing me `A_C  5`, since B is the previous row not A